# Do something before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, fadein

Tried looking this up, found some answers, but they did not work for me. I have a form that I am validating, and I want something to fade in before it submits.

```js
$('#btnConfirm').click(validateForm);

function validateForm(){
//...validation....
else{
  $('#ConfirmGiftCard').submit(function(){
    $('#ThankYou').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
    return true;
       }, 2000)
  });
 }
```

ConfirmGiftCard is the name of my form. btnConfirm is a submit button inside it.

Comment: Try using a callback function. fafeIn(delay,function(){ fadeOut()})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the your button isn't a submit button, so that it doesn't submit the form immediately on click. Make it a normal button instead (`<input type="button" />` or `<button type="button"></button>`).
2. Onclick of the button, Do your `Validation` / `fadeIn` / `fadeOut`all you need and submit the form by javascript `submit()` function when needed.

```js
$('#btnConfirm').click(validateForm);

function validateForm(){
//...validation....
   else {
      $('#ThankYou').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
          document.getElementById('ConfirmGiftCard').submit();
          //$('#ConfirmGiftCard').submit(); //This also should work, but I prefer native JS submit function because its more reliable.
          //$('#ConfirmGiftCard')[0].submit(); //Or even this works, which calls the same native JS method I used above (first one).
      });
}
```

Comment: solution with callback is better I think because 1) you not need add timeout twice (because is defined in fadeout) and 2) you can be sure when form was sent (eg after message hide complete)

Comment: This works, thank you very much. My button was a submit button, so I changed it. Also, why doesn't $('ConfirmGiftCard').submit(); work but document.getElementById('ConfirmGiftCard').submit(); does? How could I use jQuery instead of JavaScript?

Comment: @JordanCarter Did you try `$('#ConfirmGiftCard').submit();` ? If that doesn't work you can do like this `$('#ConfirmGiftCard')[0].submit();` which will call the same submit function I used.

Comment: @TareqMahmood Both work, although I did try $('#ConfirmGiftCard').submit(); before...I must have had a typo. Probably a lower case c to start. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

my solution is: submit form after message was disappired on callback.

```
$('#ThankYou').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $('#ConfirmGiftCard').submit();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/ complete function as second parameter

Comment: `$('#ConfirmGiftCard').submit(function(){ ... });` is not submitting the form, it is setting an event handler to the form.